# Upload new apk to Production Failed

Tags: android, apk

Upload failed. you uploaded a debuggable apk. for security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google play.

Upload new APK.

Comment: make debuggable false in your gradle file

Comment: Have you create a release version and using it when uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Set debuggable to false in the buildType that you are uploading and compile the apk again:

```
buildTypes {
    yourBuildType {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your build.gradle(app) file, you need to Set debuggable to false.

```
buildTypes {

    <YourBuildType> {
        debuggable false       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Upload failed. you uploaded a debuggable apk. for security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google play.

This error states that you  need to disable the debugging for the APK which you uploaded in Google play. So you need to create the build type for debug and release versions in the **build.gradle** file and use it for the same.

You need to add it to your app level gradle file -

```
YourApplicationRootFolder -> app -> build.gradle
```

You need to add it like this -

```
 buildTypes {
        debug { 
               debuggable true
            //  buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_LOGS", "true"  // This way also you can use
        }
        release { 
               debuggable false
           // buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_LOGS", "false" // This way also you can use

        }   
    }
```

So for normal running of the application simply use debug build and for publishing into store use the release build. In this you can set the other configurations as well like proguardFiles etc